# precompact coordinate ball v.s. regular coordinate ball

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I was reading Lee's smooth manifold book,there are two different theorem for basis on the manifold one state that :

> Every topological manifold has countable basis of precompact coordiante basis

Anonther one is given as follows:

> Every smooth manifold has countable basis of regular coordinate ball.

Note that the regular coordinate ball needs the chart map be smooth,except this restrition

it seems the main condition for regular coordinate ball :given regular coordinate ball $B'$ exist a larger open ball $B$ that $\overline{B'}\subset B$, need not the condition that manifold is smooth.It seems only depend on the Euclidean topology?

What makes these two theorem difference?Why one is stated in smooth manifold while the other is given in topological manifold?